# Ruby: 'next if' and 'if' statements

Tags: ruby, url, loops, syntax

I am looking at this code online on how to build a search engine (link below). Being a novice programmer, I had trouble interpreting the way the loops.

**Ruby Code:**

```
def crawl_web(urls, depth=2, page_limit = 100)
  depth.times do
    next_urls = []
    urls.each do |url|
      url_object = open_url(url)
      next if url_object == nil                                      # [1]
      url = update_url_if_redirected(url, url_object)
      parsed_url = parse_url(url_object)
      next if parsed_url == nil
      @already_visited[url]=true if @already_visited[url] == nil     # [2]
      return if @already_visited.size == page_limit                  # [3]
      next_urls += (find_urls_on_page(parsed_url, url)-@already_visited.keys)
      next_urls.uniq!
    end
    urls = next_urls
  end
end
```

**Questions:**

1. Does the program exit the block and return to the beginning of the 'urls.each' line if the url_object is nil?
2. Does this code read: "If the url we are looking at has been visited OR if the already visited URL is nil?"
3. This question is contingent on my second question. If one of the statements in question #2 are true... we should return unique next_urls only if the site size is the same as the page_limit.

Any advice helps! Thanks for reading thus far!

*Link:* http://www.skorks.com/2009/07/how-to-write-a-web-crawler-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Indeed
2. It reads: Set `@already_visited[url]` to true if we have previously not visited this url
3. Yeah, return only if the `@already_visited` "list" is the same size as the limit of the page. It doesn't actually return anything though, most of the work seems to be done on instance variable `@already_visited`, so nothing needs to be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the insight On my third question, why did the programmer decide to use 'return'? If the `@already_visited` did the work... is it necessary to return anything?

Comment: @leggooo `return` in that context is simply to break out of the entire method (consequently including breaking out of the nested blocks). As in, "ok, work is done, let's get out of here." The work after all is saved. `@already_visited` didn't _do_ the work, it's stored there (`@already_visited` is a variable which outlives the method `crawl_web` due to its scope; it's an instance variable)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Since the block ends two lines below it, is it necessary to use `return`? I am trying to understand if this convention is something I can add to other code.

Comment: @leggooo It's not necessary to return if the state of the algorithm/program is such that there will no longer be future iterations of the containing blocks. Hope that didn't sound too cryptic. Basically, if based on the state of the program there wouldn't have been any more iterations, then yeah it's not necessary to return. `return` is useful in the context in which you don't care what the state of the program is, you _know_ you're done and just want to get out of there and perhaps save a few cycles

Comment: Assuming there are more iterations of urls to look at that are passed in `crawl_web()` it makes sense to use `return` correct?